# PDO vs MySQL functions

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to rewrite some of the native mysql functions to convert to PDO functionality. However, I'm seeing a huge performance impact and my usual query now takes 2.8 seconds, up from 0.14 seconds to load data on a page. This is my original sql query where this would server as a common function to retrieve a single piece of information on one line. Mind you, the page is generating about 100 rows.

```
protected function query_s($table, $col, $where_col , $where, $return_col)
{
    $SQL = "SELECT $col FROM ".$table." WHERE $where_col='".$where."' LIMIT 1";
    try
    {
        if(!mysql_query($SQL))
        {
            throw new Exception("MySQL error: ". mysql_error());
        }
        else
        {
            $data = mysql_fetch_array($SQL);
            return $data[$return_col];  
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo "Error <p> ".$e->getMessage()." at line ".$e->getLine() ;  
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what's slowing things down. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the version after you have made the change to PDO (i.e. the slow version)? Also can you give the actual queries being run against the server (with where clauses included) for both cases?

Comment: How many rows does the table have? are the where clause fields indexed? Its not just the PDO concept that will speed everything up

Comment: There are over 3000 rows in the table ( I only display 100) , along with JOIN clauses and other class methods to retrieve specific data from other tables.

I've looked at this indexing aspect and it is fine. I'll try to get some code in after breaking up the class a bit to shown an actual example.

Comment: Did you just print the query and run that directly in MySQL client? Can you see if query is taking up time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original query is not a real code as it cannot work.

So, I suppose that the reason of the slowness you mentioned could be of the same origin - some sort of simple mistake. You need to be more attentive when writing either code or a question.

Make sure you are connecting only once per application and running sane amount of queries.

Also note that your way of handling exceptions is wrong. You shouldn't catch and echo.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. I had too many connection opened since I had written new code for the PDO. Also, what would you suggest for handling exceptions?

Comment: just don't catch them